# Flask: Getting JS to Talk to Python

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I'm writing a small Flask app and so far have only used routes that call Python functions.  So far, I just specify what Python function to call when the user hits a certain URL.

Now I want to use the value of a textBox to construct the route.  So I'll have a textBox on the page and if the user types in "Bowdoin", I want to construct a route as follows:

```
/team/<teamName>
```

and teamName will be Bowdoin in this case.

I can get the value of the textBox with basic JS but I'm not sure how to pass this value to my views file and use in a route (as described above).

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks,
bclayman

Comment: it's a bit unclear what you're trying to achieve. Is this an ajax call? redirect?

Comment: From where comes content to the route `/team/Bowdoin`?

Comment: @MauroBaraldi What do you mean?  I want to have a general route where the text after the second slash, aka "/team/RIGHT_HERE" represents the team.  each leads to a diff page for that team.  I'm just not sure how to give my Python code access to this value once I get it from the text box (using javascript).

Comment: @GG_Python So the page /team will have a text box.  When the user enters a team name and clicks a certain button, I'll retrieve the contents of that text box using javascript.  But once I do that, I'm not sure how to access it using Python within my routes file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a textbox where the user will enter the team's name, and you want to get the URL for the page for that team's name from Flask using JavaScript.

Assuming:

```
<input type="text" id="teamname" placeholder="Team name">
<button id="btn_teamname">Get team name</button>
```

and you have some handler on that button:

```
$('#btn_teamname').on('click', function() {
    // do something
});
```

First off, we'll want to use [`url_for`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.url_for) as that's the best way to generate URLs in Flask. Remember that once the user is viewing the page, Flask is done rendering it and we cannot use `url_for` without getting that from Flask (the back-end).

For this example, do the next best thing: since you know that the team name variable is simply appended to the end of the URL, get the base URL from Flask and build the final URL with JavaScript.

In your HTML somewhere, store the base URL from Flask:

```
<span id="teambaseurl" hidden>{{ url_for('teamname') }}</span>
```

Then, you can get it with JavaScript when the user clicks the button and finish the URL:

```
$('#btn_teamname').on('click', function() {
    var baseURL = $('#teambaseurl').text();
    var finalURL = baseURL + "/" + $('#teamname').val();
    // window.location.href = finalURL; // if you want to immediately navigate to that page
});
```